# Parsing JavaScript string into 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, javascript-objects

You have a string that is in a following format: "Applejack=A.J.+Applecar,Lemon+Vodka=AlfieCocktail+ Sunset + SexOnTheBeach" and etc.

In Javascript (use .split()), write code to parse a string like this(can be 100000 characters long) that puts the input in 2 different arrays(array key, array values) such that the arrays would llok like the following:

key = ["Applejack", "Lemon+Vodka"]

values = ["A.J+Applecar","AlfieCocktail+Sunset+SexOnTheBeach"]

Comment: What have you attempted?

Answer (score 0):

```
key = string.split(',').map(x=>x.split("=")[0])
values = string.split(',').map(x=>x.split("=")[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
var str = "Applejack=A.J.+Applecar,Lemon+Vodka=AlfieCocktail+ Sunset + SexOnTheBeach";
var first = str.split(',');
var keys = [];
var values = [];
for(let i = 0; i < first.length; i++){
  let in_two = first[i].split('=');
  keys.push(in_two[0]);
  values.push(in_two[1]);
}
console.log(keys);
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
let str = "Applejack=A.J.+Applecar,Lemon+Vodka=AlfieCocktail+ Sunset + SexOnTheBeach";
let allValues = str.split(','), keys = [], values = [];
allValues.forEach(value => {
    const [k,v] = value.split('=');
    keys.push(k);
    values.push(v);
})

console.log(keys,values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **map** with reduce.

```js
const str =
  "Applejack=A.J.+Applecar,Lemon+Vodka=AlfieCocktail+ Sunset + SexOnTheBeach";

const [keys, values] = str
  .split(",")
  .map((item) => item.split("="))
  .reduce(
    (acc, item) => [acc[0].concat(item[0]), acc[1].concat(item[1])],
    [[], []]
  );

console.log(keys, values);
```